# Can one set and use some axioms for calculating intersection forms of manifolds?

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, homology-cohomology, 4-manifolds

I want to calculate the intersection form of some (four?) manifolds, and I wonder is there any axioms that one can compute the intersection form of (four?) manifolds just by them? like [axioms of homology group.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eilenberg%E2%80%93Steenrod_axioms)

for example some possible candidates for that axioms (if exist) are: $Q_{M\#N}=Q_M\oplus Q_N$, $Q_{S^4}=0$, etc.

I am asking this   because I am not much easy with computing intersection form directly using cup product and I am looking for a more intuitive and easy way for that.

Comment: I don't know whether it is suitable or not: [Let $X$ and $Y$ be two closed simply-connected $4$-dimensional topological manifolds. Then $$X\text{ is homotopically equivalent to }Y\iff Q_X\text{ is isometric to }Q_Y$$](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/milnor4.pdf)

Comment: What doe Isometric mean here?

Comment: Isometric means preserving the intersection form.

Comment: The intersection form is defined in terms of cup and cap products. The magic happens because of Poincaré duality. All three of these things are well axiomatised.

Comment: Have a look into [Poincaré complexes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_complex).

Comment: This is not quite an axiomatization, but it's nevertheless interesting to view the signature as a [genus function on the complex cobordism ring.](http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Formal_group_laws_and_genera)

Comment: @Tyrone: Can you write that axioms?

Comment: You can find them axiomatised in tom Dieck's book *Algebraic Topology* see $\S17.2$  for cup products and $\S18.1$ for cap products.

Comment: @Tyrone: No, I mean directly for Intersection form not for homology and cup product.

Answer (score 0):

**Summary of comments:** The intersection form is defined in terms of cup and cap products. There is axiomatized in tom Dieck's book Algebraic Topology see §17.2 for cup products and §18.1 for cap products.

**Intersection form Using cohomology:** One can define intersection form using de Rham cohomology. This approach has been discussed in

*Moore, John Douglas*, [**Lectures on Seiberg-Witten invariants**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-540-40952-6), Lecture Notes in Mathematics 1629. Berlin: Springer (ISBN 3-540-41221-2/pbk). viii, 121 p. (2001). [ZBL1036.57014](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1036.57014).